# phpMyAdmin equivalent in python?

Tags: python, phpmyadmin

Is there a python equivalent of phpMyAdmin?

Here's why I'm looking for a python version of phpmyadmin: While I agree that phpmyadmin really rocks, I don't want to run php on my server. I'd like to move from apache2-prefork to apache2-mpm-worker. Worker blows the doors off of prefork for performance, but php5 doesn't work with worker. (Technically it does, but it's far more complicated.) The extra memory and performance penalty for having php on this server is large to me.

Comment: You might consider give us why you are looking? phpmyadmin works really well and there is no reason that you cannot let it handle the MySQL part of otherwise python development... so obviously you are looking for it for another reason. That might inform the search for possible alternatives.

Comment: Here's why I'm looking for a python version of phpmyadmin: While I agree that phpmyadmin really rocks, I don't want to run php on my server.  I'd like to move from apache2-prefork to apache2-mpm-worker.  Worker blows the doors off of prefork for performance, but php5 doesn't work with worker.  (Technically it does, but it's far more complicated.)  The extra memory and performance penalty for having php on this server is large to me.

Answer (score 12):

You can use phpMyAdmin for python project, because phpMyAdmin is meant for MySQL databases. If you are using MySQL, then regardless of whether you are using PHP or python, you can use phpMyAdmin.

Comment: But maybe the OP doesn’t want to use PHPMyAdmin, because, you know, PHPMyAdmin is not very good at all, hence the asking for something that is not PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Agreed with @Olivier'Ölbaum'Scherler. Not everyone has PHP installed on his server.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is also meant for php - I think the OP wants something written in Python.

Comment: phpMyAdmin  is very good tools but its need PHP on server.

Comment: But my server dont have PHP. I have only python install for backend.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is an alternative to phpMyAdmin. [pythonMyAdmin](https://github.com/ChipaKraken/pythonMyAdmin) doesn't seems mature.

The philosophy in python is to create the databease with the ORM and after to manage it through the web framework admin page (like the one in Django).

A lightweight alternative is using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Flask-Admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with a SQLAlchemy model.

Comment: that is so unsatisfying though. Phpmyadmin are for stuff, fixes and analysis that you cannot do with the normal backend. With python you now have to ssh to the server and connect to the db, run selects and updates manually. yukk...

Answer (score 1):

I'm basing my answer off the last sentence of your question, "[the] extra memory and performance penalty for having php on this server", because it sounds like you don't want php on that server, even though "phpmyadmin rocks".  From that, I would suggest using phpMyAdmin to manage the MySQL database remotely, which you can find an example of [here](http://archive09.linux.com/feature/130016).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything pre-existing, but there are tutorials which tell you how to make one which might be a little time consuming, but it's also educational.

Here's one method using PyQT

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_database_handling.htm

Here's another

http://apprize.info/python/gui/7.html

I'm not sure if any of those work but I might try to make them and see if i can make one to manage a lot of rows. I'm not sure if I can do it or not but we'll see. I've never even tried to make a python GUI before with any GUI package.

Comment: There's also this table but it doesnt connect to mysql. If you were able to create a connection to mysql on it and use a FOR loop to make the table it could probably work, but i dont know how you'd update the table and insert the data into the DB https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iC5mfUsUlbc

Comment: Last one. This is probably the best one i've found. It uses the Kivy GUI https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaoFCPyKSh0
EDIT: UNFORUNATELY, the code isn't posted because the uploader said they lost it when their computer crashed.. :(

Comment: This guy said he will be uploading the code for his mysql GUI here soon. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-z_HS6LVkY8